# angular ui-select-header - workarounds?

Tags: angular-ui, ui-select, angular-ui-select

I see that ui-select-header (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select-header-and-footer) is planned, but I really need a workaround until it is available, any good ideas? 
I would like to add a "Select All" button, to a control like this:

```
<ui-select ng-model="address.selected" theme="bootstrap">
<ui-select-match>{{$select.selected.formatted_address}}</ui-select-match>
<ui-select-choices repeat="address in addresses track by $index">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="address.selected">{{address.formatted_address}}
</ui-select-choices>
```